# UIImage causing memory leaks

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

Instruments is telling me that alot of memory is being allocated when I rapidly set the image name of a `UIImageview` in my app. I have a `UIImageView` that changes its image name every frame in my game. When profiled with zombie checking in instruments, the app seems to be constantly gaining live bytes at an enourmous rate. Is there a way that I can deallocate the `UIImageView`'s current image to stop it from doing this? I am using ARC.

My code to assign the `UIImageView`'s image is as follows:

`aPlanet.image = [UIImage imageNamed:tempPlanetName];`

Where aPlanet is the `UIImageView` and `tempPlanetName` is the name of the image. This is called every frame.

Comment: write your code of how you are assigning image to your imageview

Comment: You should be doing something this rediculous in an `@autoreleasepool` block.  Or use something much lighter-weight like a CALayer, that way you're not allocating two objects just to display an image once every frame.

Comment: Also, iOS will cache your images if you use `imageNamed` so beware of that.

Comment: post your code!! we can't guess what you are doing!

Comment: The code I use is now shown in the question. @borrrden what do you mean by 'cache?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `UIImage imageNamed:` it will load and cache that image file. This is intended for reuse of icons and other image resources that will be utilized more than once in your application.

Apart from it seeming somewhat unusual to update an image view with a new image every frame, you should look into alternative means of loading images that you will not need more than once - or even if you do, when you need more control over its lifecycle.

For example have a look at `UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:` (documented here: [Apple Developer Library Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithContentsOfFile%3a)). It explicitly states that this method will not do any caching of the image contents.

I hope this helps you, but for every frame I doubt that your performance will be good enough with this approach, but this is probably the topic of a different question should the need arise.

Comment: Using the `UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:` method used far more memory than `UIImage imageNamed:` method. While I understand where you are coming from, there seems to be a problem where calling the method allocates memory but then it is not deallocated. This is where I am most confused.

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not, you will have to release the image instance yourself to free the memory again.

Comment: Yes, I am using ARC. But for some reason the memory just isn't being released.

Answer (score 4):

[UIImage ImageNamed:]  method loads the image into image view and adds this newly created uiimage object to autorelease pool. To get rid of this problem you should use -

NSString *imgPath = [NSBundle mainbundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"png"];
aPlanet.image = [[UIImage alloc] ]initWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];

if you are using arc then you don't need to bother about releasing this newly allocated object of uiimage which was created using initWithContentsOfFile: method.